# How to get data from different Model in one controller in laravel5.8?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have Two Model

**1. NewJob
2. ClientInfo**

From NewJob model I inserted the data, fetched the data and displayed it nicely...

***My question is -*** In my insert model I am using html dropdown, where all clients name should display dynamically using **ClientInfo** model. How to do this?

**NewJobController code -**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $posts = NewJob::orderBy('won', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    $clients = ClientInfo::orderBy('id', 'asc');

    if ($request->ajax())
        {
            return view('Admin.NewJob.ajax', compact('posts', 'clients'));
        }
    else
        {
            return view('Admin.NewJob.newjob', compact('posts' , 'clients'));
        }
}
```

### **In view file**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$post->won}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->proj_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->department}}</td>
    <td>{{$post->district}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

#### In my Insert Model I used:

```
  <select>
     @foreach($clients as $client)
        <option value="{{$client->id}}">{{$client->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
  </select>
```

But in dropdown List no result is displaying... and also no error displaying.
Plz help... I am new in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

***In my index method I changed this line then it works fine...***

`$clients = DB::select('select * from client_infos');`